# Python - Create SOAP element structure with zeep

Tags: python, soap, zeep

I am trying to write a code with uses WS, but I encountered to an issue to build SOAP msg structure with zeep in Python.  I'm having trouble creating RTimeSeries element structure.
Can you please help to sort this out?

```
<xsd:complexType name="RXTimeSeries">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" name="RTimeSeries">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" name="RTimeSeriesData" type="b:RTimeSeriesData"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="P" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="POwner" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Python code

```
RXTimeSeries = client.get_type('ns0:RXTimeSeries')()
RTimeSeries = client.get_type('ns0:RXTimeSeries.RTimeSeries')()  # getting error here
RTimeSeries.P = "A"
RTimeSeries.POwener = "C"
RXTimeSeries.RTimeSeries = [RTimeSeries]
```

Error

```
zeep.exceptions.LookupError: No type 'RXTimeSeries.RTimeSeries' in namespace
```